# PreventDefault doesnt work in ReactJs Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preventdefault

So Im going through React Course and I did exactly what I had to do but it seems that I cant execute preventDefault function on form submit and I dont really know why if anyone has any idea please let me know form keeps refreshing when submitted

```
import './ExpenseForm.css'
import { useState } from "react";

const ExpenseForm = () => {
    const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState('');
    const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState('6');
    const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState('');


    const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
    };
    const amountChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);
    };
    const dateChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
    };

//this is the funnction that handles Submit button
    function submitHandler (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("go")
        const expenseData = {
            title: enteredTitle,
            amount: enteredAmount,
            date: new Date(enteredDate)
        }
    };
    return (
// this is the form and pointer to function that should execute when form is submitted
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="new-expense__controls">
                <div className="new-expense__control">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={titleChangeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div className="new-expense__control">
                    <label>Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" onChange={amountChangeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div className="new-expense__control">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input type="date" min="2019-01-01" max="2022-12-31" onChange={dateChangeHandler}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__actions">
// this is the button that submits
                <button type='submit'>Add Expense</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default ExpenseForm;
```

I checked everything but I ant seem to solve problem at first I thought that I had syntax error but I didnt find anything...

Comment: Why not simply `<button type='button' onClick={clickHandler}>Add Expense</button>` ? -- a `type="button"` won't submit the form.

Comment: Because I will have to listen to submit and not click after some time

Comment: What does it mean "I cant execute preventDefault function on form submit"? What is happening when you do so?

Comment: @YuriyYakym It means that it doesn't work the page still refreshes...